# SendKeys.SendWait function - send special key to application

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I try to figure out how to send the character "^" (not the CTRL command) to a external text window.

This different codes I have tried:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^");
SendKeys.SendWait("(^)");
Sendkeys.SendWait("{^}"); //This should be the right code, but it doesn't work either
```

None of those would type me the character "^" in a text field.
If I send normal text to the window it appears in the window. The "^" cannot be typed somehow.
I had a look in the MSDN and in the Online Help, but couldn't find anything close to that problem.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To send the character "^" using `SendKeys.SendWait()`, you need to think about which keys you're actually pressing. On an en-US keyboard it's Shift & 6, which translates to this:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("+6");
```

So whichever key combination you use to generate the "^" character, enter those keys into the `SendKeys.SendWait()` call.

Comment: Depending on the keyboard layout of course. Not everyone uses US-en as their keyboard layout.